# java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Rejected command because thread-pool queueSize is at rejection threshold

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

We suddenly started receiving following error in out application services, we did not make any change to config in recent time.  Could any one provide some information regarding error?

```
Caused by: com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: xxx service could not be queued for execution and no fallback available.
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Rejected command because thread-pool queueSize is at rejection threshold.
```

Configuration in gateway are:

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.strategy=THREAD
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=360000
hystrix.threadpool.default.coreSize=40
hystrix.command.default.circuitBreaker.forceClosed=true
hystrix.threadpool.default.maxQueueSize=2000
hystrix.threadpool.default.queueSizeRejectionThreshold=1800

zuul.routes.<instance>.path=/<instance>/**
zuul.routes.<instance>.serviceId=<instance>
zuul.routes.<instance>.sensitiveHeaders=
<instance>.ribbon.OkToRetryOnAllOperations=true
<instance>.ribbon.MaxAutoRetriesNextServer=1
<instance>.ribbon.MaxAutoRetries=0
hystrix.command.<instance>.execution.isolation.strategy=THREAD
hystrix.command.<instance>.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=360000
hystrix.threadpool.<instance>.coreSize=40
hystrix.command.<instance>.circuitBreaker.forceClosed=true
hystrix.threadpool.<instance>.maximumSize=100
hystrix.threadpool.<instance>.queueSizeRejectionThreshold=80
```

We were having the coreSize, forceClosed, maxQueueSize and quoteSizeRejectionThreshold as default and not it is configured this level.  It still has the issue.  We tried restart Gateway and Eureka instance.

Comment: Facing same issue. Did you get the solution?

Comment: Hi @AnkurRaiyani I did not get any response, I fixed it by increasing the thread pool properties. hystrix.threadpool.yourService.coreSize=40
hystrix.threadpool.yourService.maximumSize=100
hystrix.threadpool.yourService.queueSizeRejectionThreshold=80                          If this did not help try setting hystrix.command.yourService.circuitBreaker.forceClosed=true

Comment: Thanks for the update

Answer (score 0):

By default each command will create its own 'named' thread pool and every time an instance of that command is executed, a thread from that thread pool will be chosen and used.
Try with below configuration.

```
hystrix.command.<instance>.coreSize=40
hystrix.command.<instance>.circuitBreaker.forceClosed=true
hystrix.command.<instance>.maximumSize=100
hystrix.command.<instance>.queueSizeRejectionThreshold=80
```

[Reference](https://docs.steeltoe.io/api/v3/circuitbreaker/hystrix.html)